# How to read html form data though Java file in android?

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I want to use HTML instead of XML file in android. so using WebView in xml and create a HTML file in assets folder and wrote code in java. while compiling, I got a output. BUT when using form, how to get elements from the form to MAIN_ACTIVITY.java file ?

Following are the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText e;
    @   Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); /*setContentView(R.layout.my);*/
    WebView mWebView = null;
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new.html"); /*e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name1);*/
    }
```

Comment: try adding this code to question instead in comment

Comment: xml file.
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

Comment: new.html
<html>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<form action="MainActivity">
<input type="text" id="name1" name="name1">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

You need to build javascript bridge, see the following [example](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2012/03/16/android-development-javascript-bridge-example-fully-explained/).
Also you can use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) which already has HTML platform that interact with Java code and it's cross platform.